# Getting the current product ID in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the **WooCommerce plugin** in **Wordpress** for a project that i am currently working on.

Normally, when you want to buy something (from a customer perspective) you'll add the product to the cart and buy it.

The problem is, the client I am working for doesn't want to use the cart.
Instead, he wants customers to (when they click on a product) go to a page where they'll need to fill out their name, email adress etc. and send an email for a request to buy the specific product.

But I am running into a little bit of trouble. Creating a form and sending an email is not a problem, but I need to post the current product ID to the form in order for it to work and somehow I cannot find a way to post it to the page. Is there a specific variable in which the current product ID is stored? or how do I get the product ID for me to store in a variable so I can post it to my form?

Many thanks,
René

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get it inside Wordpress like this :

```
$id = $product->id;
```

```
$id = $post->id // Not working
```

**EDIT (according to comment):** Since *WooCommerce 3*, product properties should not be accessed directly, so `$product->id` will log a PHP error. Instead use `$product->id()`.

Comment: I was getting null with $post->id but $product->id worked for me. thnx...

Comment: `$product->id` works best with WooCommerce products

Comment: Thank you yadavr and Avishai for your feedback, I've corrected my answer.

Comment: Since WooCommerce 3, product properties should not be accessed directly, so $product->id will log a PHP error. Instead use $product->id()

Answer (score 4):

Latest method (WooCommerce 3.0.8) is `$product->get_id()`